# How to use a variable that is outside of handlebars #each scope?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Let's say I pass two JSON objects to a page and then I want to have a nested `#each` in handlebars:

```
orders = [-{id: 1}]
techs = [-{id: 2}]

{{#each orders as |order|}}
     {{order.id}}
     {{#each techs as |tech|}}
           {{tech.id}}
     {{/each}}        
{{/each}}
```

`{{order.id}}` returns `1` but `{{tech.id}}` doesn't return anything.
Is there a way to have the second `#each` access the `techs` variable?

---

Ok here's the solution:

```
orders = [-{id: 1}]
techs = [-{id: 2}]

{{#each orders as |order|}}
     {{order.id}}
     {{#each ../techs as |tech|}}
           {{tech.id}}
     {{/each}}        
{{/each}}
```

I just added `../` to techs.

Comment: "Nested handlebars paths can also include `../` segments, which evaluate their paths against a parent context." See: http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you so much.